# How to make tar globbing work with the 'change directory' option

Tags: wildcards, tar

I have the followin directory structure:

```
base/
   files/
   archives/
   scripts/
```

I want a script to run from `scripts/`, compress files that match `results.*.log` in `files/` into a gzipped tar archive in `archives/`.

I'm trying the following command:

```
tar czfC ../archives/archive.tar.gz ../files results.*.log
```

But I get

```
tar: results.*.log: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

While

```
tar czfC ../archives/archive.tar.gz ../files results.a.log
```

works as expected. Also

```
tar czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz ../files/results.*.log
```

works the way I would like, except it adds the prefix `files/` to the file and also emits a warning:

```
tar: Removing leading `../' from member names
```

So my conclusion is that `tar` globbing doesn't work properly when using the `-C` option. Any advice on how I make this work in a simple manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write it the more portable way:

```
(cd ../files && tar cf - results.*.log) | 
  gzip -9 > ../archives/archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: The glob will still be interpreted in the current directory, before the `cd` happens.

Comment: @vonbrand, no, of course it won't. `&&` is like `;` or newline, it separates two commands. It's like saying that after running `cd`, any glob would expand files in the previous directory.

Comment: You are right. One never finishes learning.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "tar globbing", the globbing is done by the shell. And the shell has no idea that `tar -C somedir` will do its work in `somedir`, any globs are expanded in the current directory.

Comment: Indeed, if `results.a.log` exists in the  directory from which the script is run, it works. But I don't understand why this happens, since `-C` stands for change directory, so the current directory should be the one with `results.a.log`. I can't accept your answer because you don't offer a solution.

Comment: The shell takes the command, expands globs in the current directory, manufactures the arguments from the above, and launches the `tar` program, which changes directory much later. Can't "solve" your problem, sorry. The only way out is to move into the directory where you want to glob, or do the globbing in the directory and save its results in a file or variable.

Answer (score 1):

I finally used

```
tar czfC ../archives/archive.tar.gz ../files `find ../files/results.*.log -printf "%f\n"`
```

Comment: While that may work for you, it's a pretty complex way to do it. Furthermore, it won't work with file names containing special characters such as whitespace. Use one of the sane methods that have been proposed in answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can let `find` do the globbing and omit the 'change directory' option to `tar` by removing the `files/` prefix before creating the tarfile.

The `--no-recursion` option to `tar` is optional since no directories are going to be archived.

```
cd base/scripts

# gnutar
# printf '%s\000' ../files/results.*.log |  # find alternative
find ../files -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "results.*.log" -print0 | 
   gnutar --transform="s|^\.\{0,1\}\.\{0,1\}/\{0,1\}files/||" -cf - --null --no-recursion -T - | 
   gzip -9 > ../archives/archive.tar.gz
gnutar -tf ../archives/archive.tar.gz | nl
gnutar -xzf ../archives/archive.tar.gz

# bsdtar
find ../files -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "results.*.log" -print0 | 
   bsdtar -s "|^\.\{0,1\}\.\{0,1\}/\{0,1\}files/||" -cf - --null --no-recursion -T - | 
   gzip -9 > ../archives/archive.tar.gz
bsdtar -tf ../archives/archive.tar.gz | nl
bsdtar -xzf ../archives/archive.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is to write something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ../files
tar zcf ../archives/archive.tar.gz results.*.log
cd ../scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not tar that does the globbing, it's the shell. You're first telling the shell to do globbing, then telling tar to change directories. Since tar is receiving a list of file names relative to the original directories, this doesn't work.

The easiest solution by far is to let the shell change the directory. Interactively:

```
cd ../files
tar czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz  results.*.log
cd -
```

In a script:

```
(
  cd ../files &&
    tar czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz  results.*.log
)
```

or

```
(
  cd ../files &&
    tar czf -  results.*.log
) >../archives/archive.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR (solution without `cd` or null bytes)

```
tar -czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz -C ../files $(find ../files -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "results.*.log" -printf "%f\n")
```

or

```
find ../files -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "results.*.log" -printf "%f\n" | tar  -czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz -C ../files -T -
```

Note: if you want to work with file names containing special characters such as whitespace us the SuperUser answer below using null bytes that won't be embeddable in most programming languages.

### What does not work

There is a limitation to the tar directory option

```
       -C, --directory=DIR
              Change to DIR before performing any operations.  This option is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
```

The issue with the following command is that the shell globing in `results.*.log` is expended before the tar option is applied, so in the current directory.

```
tar czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz -C ../files results.*.log
```

The below command works but it includes all files in `../files` and not only the wanted logs.

```
tar czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz -C ../files .
```

The below command works but will store the relative path and not just the filename as we want.

```
tar czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz -C ../files ../files/results.*.log
```

The following command from [this SuperUser answer (How do I remove the full path when doing a tar.gz compression?)](https://superuser.com/questions/692578/how-do-i-remove-the-full-path-when-doing-a-tar-gz-compression#answer-1629133) works of executed from a shell directly but the issue is that you can't execute that in programming languages because most of them won't allow a null byte in a string (eg. `string contains null byte (ArgumentError)` in Ruby).

```
find ../files -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "results.*.log" -printf "%P\0" | tar --null --remove-files -czf ../archives/archive.tar.gz -C ../files -T -
```