# creating a tar archive without including parent directory

Tags: tar

I am trying to create a graphical program for my script.

Inside the script I use tar to create a tar archive.

From the graphical program I get the full name of file that I want to create a tar archive.

```
tar -cvf temp.tar /home/username/dir1/dir2/selecteddir
```

My tar archive includes home, username, dir1, dir2 and selecteddir while i want tar to create archive only including selecteddir.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can use the `-C` option of `tar` to accomplish this:

```
tar -C /home/username/dir1/dir2 -cvf temp.tar selecteddir
```

From the man page of `tar`:

```
-C directory
         In c and r mode, this changes the directory before adding the following files.  
         In x mode, change directories after opening the archive but before extracting 
         entries from the archive.
```

Comment: do you know how i can split $path into selecteddir and path upto /home/username/dir1/dir2 so I can user -C option

Comment: @SujitMaharjan you can use `dirname` to extract everything until "selecteddir" and `basename` to extract "selecteddir". Try the two commands with the $path as argument.

Comment: Worth adding that this is valid for both GNU and BSD Tar.

Comment: Note that you can't use globbing with the -C option. `tar -C /home/username/dir1/dir2 -cvf temp.tar '*.csv'` won't work.

Comment: Doesn't work: tar: selecteddir: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Comment: Special use case `tar -C /home/username/dir1/dir2/selecteddir -cvf temp.tar .` to only reflect the tree of selecteddir witout 'selcteddir/' preceding every filename.

Comment: @grenix but now you have `./` prefixing all files! See @mpen's answer

Comment: thats true, but for further processing the preceding './' does not harm for many cases. Even if you assume another base direcory '/base/./path_to_file' is effectively the same than '/base/path_to_file'. Furthermore it ressembles the output format of 'find . -type f' which might be of advatage for some use cases.

Comment: Reason, why you can't use globbing with Asterisk `*`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71464/408419

Answer (score 25):

There are two methods that you can use to approach this problem.

The first one, in my opinion, is easier. Simply `cd` into directory directly above the one you want to compress. In this case it would be `dir2`.

```
$ cd /home/username/dir1/dir2/
$ tar -cvf temp.tar selecteddir
```

The second way is to use the option `--transform` which takes a `sed` expression and runs it against the files names. Note: you will have to escape `/` in the `sed` expression.

```
$ tar -cvf temp.tar /home/username/dir1/dir2/selecteddir --transform='s/\/home\/username\/dir1\/dir2\///g'
```

Comment: Does the first method need a dot (.) on the end? I tried it without and got: `tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive`. When I have the dot, it annoyingly makes the root contain a directory named `.`. So, close but not perfect.

Comment: Further to my previous comment. I solved my issue. `$ cd /home/username/dir1/dir2/ &&
tar -cvf temp.tar selecteddir *` worked for me. Using asterisk instead of a dot `.`. Update: Woops - Although I lost the hidden files.

Comment: I know it's an old post but just in case: using a different delimiter may be easier than escaping, e.g. `--transform='s:/home/username/dir1/dir2/::g'`

Answer (score 20):

First, go to the working directory,

```
cd /your/working/directory/
```

Then use magic `*` :-)

```
tar -cvf temp.tar *
```

Comment: I'm trying to archive hidden directories and if I add them directly (No *) it works, but when using * it only adds the name of the archive to the archive ...

Comment: You can use * and .* to get both regular and hidden files.  You can also use --exclude thearchive.tar to avoid archiving some files

Answer (score 11):

Actually, I found a problem using Ketan's answer

> tar -C /home/username/dir1/dir2 -cvf temp.tar selecteddir

When you want to just copy all files just in dir2, just all files then I first come out the idea:

> tar -C /home/username/dir1/dir2 -cvf temp.tar *

However, when you are not in dir2 directory, it would cause problem since * would tar files in your current diectroy. And I fixed the problem using command below:

> ```
>  tar -C /home/username/dir1/dir2 -cvf temp.tar ./
> ```

Comment: But then your _temp.tar_ archive contains `.` as a root folder.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid that dot dir, you can strip it after the fact:

```
tar czC /path/to/dir . --transform='s,^\./,,' >| foo.tgz
```

This will create an archive with only the *contents* of `/path/to/dir`.

Comment: This is a cool feature!

Comment: Thanks, But how to remove the 0 byte `.` folder beside other files in the archive? This method still keeps that `.` folder inside archive.

Comment: @DummyBeginner I don't know, `(cd /foo && tar czvf /bar/archive.tar.gz * .*)` seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @mpen Yes, I think so., Although the `.*` at the end of `cd /foo && tar czvf /bar/archive.tar.gz * .*` is apparently redundant.

Comment: @DummyBeginner Depends on your bash flags, whether or not you have the `dotglob` flag set I think it is

Comment: @mpen Ah I see, wasn't thinking about hidden files at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional and portable way to do it is with:

```
(cd /home/username/dir1/dir2 && tar cf - selecteddir | gzip) > temp.tar.gz
```

(or `lzop`/`lz4`/`xz` your preferred compressor; or you could skip compression altogether if you didn't care about saving space).

To uncompress into that same directory, you just reverse the pipeline:

```
(cd /home/username/dir1/dir2 && gzip -d | tar xpf -) < temp.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `tar` a bunch of files without any parent folder, you can `cd` into the folder and then tar `.` (indicating the current directory) while specifying `../yourfiles.tar` as the output file. For example, if you want to `tar` all the files in the `yourfiles` folder, then `cd` to the parent folder of `yourfiles` and type run this:

```
cd yourfiles && tar -cf ../yourfiles.tar . && cd ../
```

The parent of `yourfiles` will now also contain `yourfiles.tar`.

Note that when you extract `yourfiles.tar` with `tar -xf yourfiles.tar` it will extract all the files into the *current* directory, rather than creating a folder. However, if you right-click and "Extract here" in Ubuntu, it will create a folder called `yourfiles` to put the files in ("incorrect" behavior, but better UX).