# how to add files from a folder to archive instead of the folders itself?

Tags: tar

this is not a duplicate of [creating a tar archive without including parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168357/creating-a-tar-archive-without-including-parent-directory)

If I do `tar -czf archive directory`, directory will be added to the archive. I want to add the files of the folder `directory` not the directory itself, how?
please suggest answer that does not involve `cd`ing to `directory`

this is not a duplicate of what its showing:
I have a directory called `somedir` with contents as `abc`, `xyz`:

```
ls somedir
abc xyz
```

I want to make archive that will contain files `abc`, `xyz`, not `somedir` folder

**Update**:
if i use the command `tar -C /home/username/dir1/dir2 -cvf temp.tar yourarchive` (which the answer to the question of which my question is called duplicate of)

i get this:

[image]

what I wanted is `tar czf archive.tar.gz -C yourarchive .`, I get this (**which is close enough of what I wanted**):

[image]

what I wanted was is this (directly files, no folder):

[image]

Comment: This seems like an exact duplicate as far as I can tell. `tar czf archive -C directory .` will create an `archive` file containing `abc` and `xyz`. I am therefore closing this. If I'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: @terdon you are wrong, by using `tar czf archive -C directory .` i am getting archive that contains a folder `.` which has files in it. on the other hand if I open the archive i want to make, i must see directly files and no folder

Comment: But that makes no difference at all! If you untar it, you just get the files, no directory. The `.` is implied, anyway. Can you give an example where there is a difference?

Comment: @terdon I hope I am clear now, please reply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-C`:

```
tar czf archive -C directory .
```

This instructs `tar` to use `directory` as its working directory, and archive everything contained in the directory (`.`).

Using `-C` is nearly equivalent to using `cd`; `archive` above is interpreted relative to the current directory when `tar` starts, then `tar` changes its working directory to `directory` before interpreting `.`.

I'm not sure how widespread support for `tar -C` is, but any Linux distribution should support it.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
tar cvf archive.tar -C somedir $(ls somedir)
```

where

- `cvf` will **C**reate **V**erbose(ly) **F**ile `Archive.tar`
- `-C somedir` will instruct tar to  use `somedir`
- `$(ls somedir )` list file in somedir and `$( )` passe result as argument

Edit:

As pointed in comment, use `ls -A` (not <s>ls -a</s>) to list dotfile.

Comment: Or `$(ls -A somedir)` to also include the dotfiles.

Comment: This will break on files containing whitespace.

Comment: @Archemar being root has nothing to do with `ls -A`; adding `-A` includes dotfiles except `.` and `..`, which is necessary to replicate `tar`'s behaviour with directories (it archives everything, including hidden files).

Comment: @StephenKitt It seems the other way round, ls will not list dotfile for normal user, whereas root will see it.

Comment: Unless you have aliases which provide different options to `ls`, plain `ls` ignores dotfiles for all users, including `root`, `ls -a` lists all files including dotfiles and `.` and `..`, `ls -A` lists all files including dotfiles except `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [pax(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pax), which is the posix successor to tar, but it never really caught on. It can write tar files and it can do the filename transformation you want to do:

```
pax -wzf archive -s '|directory/\?||' directory
```

That breaks down to:

- `-w` write an archive (same as `-c` for tar)
- `-z` compress archive (same as tar)
- `-f archive` write to file `archive` (same as tar)
- `-s '|directory/\?||'` substitute filenames in the archive. Replace the string `directory` with an optional `/` with the empty string. The optional `/` is needed as the directory itself does not end with a `/`, but all the other members have that `/`. This does not need to be anchored to the start of the string (`^`) because it replaces only the first match (like `sed(1)`) and all files will start with `directory/\?`

To be explicit you could add:

- `-x ustar` write a POSIX tar file

but that is the default.

You should be able to find pax in your Linux or BSD package repository. There seems to be a GNU pax, but I don't know the state of that. Debian seems to have a BSD version of pax.